# Special symbol "." in routing of mvc 5 site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and have problem with links like `/Music/artist/R.E.M.`

I mean when I put params to link I use `Url.Encode()` function but it leave `.`

```
 string test = "/Music/artist/" + Url.Encode("R.E.M."); //"/Music/artist/R.E.M."
```

Live example

```
http://freemusiclib.com/Music/artist/R.E.M.
```

What I should do with those `.` symbols? How to pass them in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```